# Print a matrix in following format for given number

Tags: c#

For a given number `n` I have to print the following matrix (`n = 3` example):

```
 3 3 3 3 3 
 3 2 2 2 3 
 3 2 1 2 3 
 3 2 2 2 3 
 3 3 3 3 3
```

the count of rows and columns should be `(2 * n) - 1`. I tried to find the pattern but couldn't figured it out. Any help would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Use multidimensional int array to create 2D matrix with specific row-column order, then assign values with given criteria and print results. Just show your code and we'll check it.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto: *jagged* arrays (i.e. array of array `int[][]`) instead of *2D* ones (`int[,]`) can do the task even better.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
private static int[][] Matrix(int n) {
  // Create arrays
  int[][] result = Enumerable.Range(0, 2 * n - 1)
    .Select(_ => new int[2 * n - 1])
    .ToArray();

  // Feed arrays
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    int from = i - 1;
    int to = 2 * n - i - 1;
    int v = n - i + 1;

    for (int j = from; j <= to; ++j) {
      result[from][j] = v;
      result[to][j] = v;
      result[j][from] = v;
      result[j][to] = v;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

....

int n = 3;

String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Matrix(n)
  .Select(line => String.Join(" ", line)));

Console.Write(report);
```

Output for `n = 3` is

```
   3 3 3 3 3
   3 2 2 2 3
   3 2 1 2 3
   3 2 2 2 3
   3 3 3 3 3
```

And for `n = 4`:

```
   4 4 4 4 4 4 4
   4 3 3 3 3 3 4
   4 3 2 2 2 3 4
   4 3 2 1 2 3 4
   4 3 2 2 2 3 4
   4 3 3 3 3 3 4
   4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version that doesn't use any intermediate storage:

```
static void printMatrix(int n)
{
    int x = 2*n - 1;

    for (int i = 0, p = n; i < x; ++i, p += (i > x/2) ? 1 : -1)
    {
        for (int j = 0, q = n; j < x; ++j, q += (j > x/2) ? 1 : -1)
            Console.Write(Math.Max(p, q) + " ");

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

This works as follows:

The outer loop (i) and inner loop (j) both go from 0 .. 2*n-1.

However, the values that we want to print (`p` and `q`) start at `n` and decrease until halfway across/down the matrix, at which point they start increasing again.

We can determine whether to increment or decrement these values by checking the loop variable to see if it is halfway across/down the matrix yet. If it is, we decrement, otherwise we increment.

That's what this is doing: `p += (i > x/2) ? 1 : -1`.

If `i > x/2` then the value `1` will be used for the increment, otherwise `-1` will be used for the increment (i.e. it will be decremented).

(Similarly for `q`.)

The final piece of the puzzle is that the value we want to use is actually the *maximum* of `p` and `q`. If you inspect the matrix, you will see that if you consider each row value and each column value, the maximum of each is used for the corresponding cell.

Hence the use of `Math.Max(p, q)` in the output.

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit ?

Comment: @SillyVolley Sure, I'll add comments to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here a simpler solution less complicated and fastest here so far:

```
private static void printMatrix(int n)
{
    // length of the matrix in one dimension
    int length = (2 * n) - 1;
    // iterate through y axis of the matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int value = n;
        // iterate through x axis of the matrix
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(value);

            if (i > j && i + j < length - 1)
            {
                value--;
            }
            else if (i <= j && i + j >= length - 1)
            {
                value++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

**Explanation for the if statements**

First take a look on the matrix like it would be an array and look at the indexes and values and what changes when iterating through the array in the two `for` statements whereas the value of `i` is for the `y axis, from up to down` and the value of `j` is for the `x axis, from left to right`.

```
// +1 and -1 means the changes of the values

0,0    0,1    0,2    0,3    0,4    // values of i,j (first is i, second is j)
[3]    [3]    [3]    [3]    [3]    // printed value

1,0    1,1    1,2    1,3    1,4
[3] -1 [2]    [2]    [2] +1 [3]

2,0    2,1    2,2    2,3    2,4
[3] -1 [2] -1 [1] +1 [2] +1 [3]

3,0    3,1    3,2    3,3    3,4
[3] -1 [2]    [2]    [2] +1 [3]

4,0    4,1    4,2    4,3    4,4
[3]    [3]    [3]    [3]    [3]
```

As you can see, the value changes only in specific circumstances.

And this happens `-1` if `i > j` and if `i + j < length - 1`, otherwise after index `3,1` you will have wrong values, after that it shouldn't subtract the value any more. 
This two if statements lead us to the first statement in the code:

```
if (i > j && i + j < length - 1)
{
    value--;
}
```

Now it also happens `+1` if `i + j >= length - 1` but that not other values like `3,1` also add `+1` to the value it only increments it, if `i <= j`, which leads us to the second if-statement in the code:

```
else if (i <= j && i + j >= length - 1)
{
    value++;
}
```

If none of these statements are true, the value simply stays the same as it should.

Comment: @SillyVolley have a look at my explanation. It helps really taking a paper and write the values down as i tried to do in my explanation. Feel free to ask if something still is unclear.